# How to display which mode I'm in while in VI

Tags: command-line

So learning how to navigate and edit in VI but the tutorial I'm following on Udemy (using Ubuntu) shows a slightly different Vi where if they are in command mode or insert mode, the terminal window will show which mode they're in.

Where can I configure this?

Basically what I would like to know is how can I display terminal to tell me which mode I'm in.

EDIT: using vi, version 8.0.1453 on Kubuntu at the moment

EDIT2: I installed VIM and that'll do what I need, thanks anyway mates

Comment: Are you actually using `vi` or rather `vim`? If you’re not sure, `vi --version` and/or `file /etc/alternatives/vi` will help.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you are seeing in the tutorials?

Comment: Some of the examples are to edit a text file within vi as well as navigating around the document, but nothing tells me which mode am, which is abit frustrating as I could be moving up the document but unintentionally editing it